# Props passed by propsData are undefined when creating a Vue component at runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

**What I'm trying to do:**

To simplify the problem: Let's say that I have a single page Vue component called `A`, that that component has a prop called `x`. I have a view called `B` where I have a button that creates and adds a new `A` component when clicked.

**The way I tried to do it:**

First of all, I'm aware of the possibility of storing the component's code in a constant and reusing that again and again. But that's not what I want, I have my component in a separate file, I want to use that.

This is how I do it:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="editor" class="editor" ref="editor">
        
    </div>
    <button @click="addBlock('heading')">Add a block</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import A from "...";
export default {
  name: "B",
  components: {
    A
  },
  methods: {
    addBlock(val) {
      console.log("Adding a block: ", val);
      var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(A, {
        propsData: {
          x: val
        },
      });
      var instance = new ComponentClass();
      instance.$mount();
      this.$refs.editor.insertBefore(
        instance.$el,
        this.$refs.editor.children[this.$refs.editor.children.length - 3] // I have some othe elements there that I want to keep at the end
      );
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

**The problem:**

- The new component is created and added to the page, but, the `x` property of that component is `undefined`.
- Although the new component is added to the page, its is not showing in the components tree in the vue devtools.
- Finally, the `A` component has an event called `save`, in the `B` view, I have a method called save too (it's under `methods`), I want to bind that event to my method, I can't just add `@save: "this.save"` to the `propsData`. What's the correct way of doing that?

Comment: You might consider using the `<component />` element and setting `:is` and `v-bind` to set your component and props.  This application is exactly what those are for.

Comment: For your save, you can either pass a function in as a prop, or emit a save event.